# Python - Double integral of matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, sympy, calculus

I want to solve an equation which has matrix in it with Python.

[image: Here is a picture of the equation]

I tried to use the scimpy.integrate.dblquad, but I don't figure how to use it.

Here is my code :

> import numpy as np
> import sympy as smp

> x = smp.symbols('x')
> y = smp.symbols('y')
>
> B = np.array([[2*x, 0., 0],[0, 2*y, 0]])
> BT = np.transpose(B)
>
> MinY = 0
> MaxY = 0.1
> MinX = 0
> MaxX = 0.2
> f = lambda x, y: BT*50*B*10
> k = integrate.dblquad(f,MinX, MaxX, MinY, MaxY)[0]

I get this: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (2,3)

how I can correct my code ?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text into actual text? Can you please read about [how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541) and apply what you learn to improve your question post? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.  See also: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting) and [/editing-help](/editing-help).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.